# Eslint no-console rule passes console.log();

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I am using [eslint](https://eslint.org/) to lint my angular project, and I want any of console prints to be removed

so I used [no-console](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console) rule as.

```
....
"no-console": "error",
...
```

It's validating `console.debug` but isn't validating `console.log();`, `console.warn();`, `console.error();` etc.

any reason behind that? I'm using `"eslint": "^7.26.0",`

Comment: Sometimes you would need to restart your IDE or VS Code to take effect.

Comment: I tired it but still no success

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following syntax:

```
"no-console": ["error", { "allow": ["error"] }],
```

This will validate log but allow error. Default syntax allows for console.log.